# clear session specific timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I have an express app where I set a timeout on a request and clear the timeout on a request of another route if a condition is met. The problem is that I cannot store the timeout in session (which is normal because it's a function, not something where you can JSON.stringify()).

I tried to make a global variable: let timeout and assign the timeout to the variable but this does not work off course because I have multiple users. So every time another user sends a request the timeout variable will be reassigned.

A small example of what I would like to do:

```
const route1 = (req, res) => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        // do something
    }, 1000);

    req.session.timeout = timeout; // I know this does not work, but it is an example of what I would like to do
};

const route2 = (req, res) => {

    // if condition is met clear the above timeout for this user/session
    clearTimeout(req.session.timeout); // I know this does not work, but it is an example of what I would like to do
};
```

I could store every timeout in an object with as key the sessionId but I am not sure this is needed and/or the right way to do something like this.

Comment: Why can't you use the session? Also, is the timeout supposed to be applied per user or globally? i.e. could one user start the timer and another cancel?

Comment: Because you can't store references to function's in a session (not that I know off). The timeouts are just something I do for good reasons, users can't control this.

Comment: you realise `timeout` in this example isn't a function, it's an integer ID so should be fine.

Comment: What do you mean? TImeout is a reference to the setTimeout function

Comment: yes but it's an integer value, it's not a reference to the function itself. I don't see why you would have trouble serializing the value into the session.

Comment: Exactly what @James said. `setTimeout` returns an integer that identifies a timer. It's not a function reference and there's no problem with serializing it. You could even create a global array that would hold the timer identifiers which would then allow you to clear each of them with clearTimeout.

Comment: Ow, I will check this in a moment. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry but this is not true, could you give me an example?

Comment: I've just checked the behavior of setTimeout in node and you're right - it works differently than in browsers. In fact, [it worked](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.1/api/timers.html) as we described in early versions of node. Currently, it returns an object that represents the scheduled timer instead of its ID. Instead of serializing the `setTimeout` result and storing it in your session, you could create a global array that would hold something like `{userId, setTimeoutResult}`. Then you could access the array in `route2`, find the given user and clear the stored timeout.

Comment: Hi, yes I did this too. Thanks for your help. I will answer my own question with what I did. Thanks again!

Comment: @Laurent yes apologies, my mistake on that. I should've checked the docs first, it's sometimes too easy to just assume these things since they work very similarly.

Comment: I find it weird also they would make this different in nodeJS. I think this is because nodeJS needed to create there own because they don't have the window object? Thanks anyway for the good intentions!

Comment: @Laurent I think it's more to do with the fact you may want to change the behaviour of the timer in Node given its an application e.g. you can [unref](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref) a timer as to not keep the process alive should the timer take longer than expected.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I achived this:

I create a new JS file with an empty object:

```
let mapper = {

};

module.exports = mapper;
```

This is how I used it:

```
const route1 = (req, res) => {
    const {id: sessionId} = req.session;

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        // do something
    }, 1000);

    mapper[sessionId] = timeout; // I put the timeout instance in the object with as key the sessionId
};

const route2 = (req, res) => {
    const {id: sessionId} = req.session;
    // if condition is met clear the above timeout for this user/session
    clearTimeout(mapper[sessionId]); // I get the Timeout instance from the object
};
```

Then the problem was how do I clean this file up if people logout or the session is destroyed/removed.

I exported my store in my app.js file:

```
exports.app = app;
exports.store = store;
```

This is how I cleaned up the mapper object in my server.js file:

```
const mapper = require('./mapperFile');
const store = require('./app').store;

setInterval(() => {
    const ids = Object.keys(mapper);

    for (let i = 0; i<  ids.length; i++) { // I loop through all the sessionIds (the keys of the Object)
        store.get(ids[i], (err, store) => { // I get the store for this key
            if (err) {
                // console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                if (!store) {
                    delete mapper[ids[i]]; // If the session is removed I delete this from the object
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, 2000); // I don't know if 2 seconds is a good time but you get the idea
```

I hope this helped someone else. I still don't know if this is the correct way to do it, but it works for me.

Comment: The only problem you would have with this approach is scalability, it wouldn't work across a multi-process architecture.

Comment: Hi @James, I am not sure this is the place to do this but could you perhaps tell me a bit more about a multi process architecture. I thought node was single threaded. I am not that good at such topics but would like to learn more and I have the feeling you know a lot. Is there a way I could contact you on stack? Thanks!